# Issue with react-table: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm working on a react frontend which calls an API and attempts to take the return JSON data and put in a table format using react-table. I've been stumped for a couple days now on this. I'm using only functions and hooks with React. My main component is:

```
const [tableJSON, setTableJSON] = useState('');
const [inquiryCount, setInquiryCount] = useState(1);
const [sortByColumn] = useState('INQ_RECEIVE_DATE');
const [sortByDirection] = useState('DESC');

const mid = memberId['usr-memberid'];

    const getInquiryData = async () => {
        try {
            const resp = await INQUIRY_API.inquiryList({ "memberId": mid, inquiryCount, sortByColumn, sortByDirection }, token['usr-token']);
            setTableJSON(resp);
            //return (resp);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("Data load failed: " + error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getInquiryData();
    }, [inquiryCount]);


...
...
...
...

<HomeTableRT tabledata={tableJSON} />
```

My HomeTableRT component looks like:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import '../../css/table.css';
import { useTable, useSortBy } from 'react-table'

const columns = React.useMemo(() => [
        { Header: 'Submitted by', accessor: 'submittedBy' },
        { Header: 'Inquiry PDF', accessor: 'inquiryId_pdf', },
        { Header: 'Report Type', accessor: 'reportType', },],
        [])

//const data = React.useMemo(() => JSON.stringify(props.tabledata), [props.tabledata])
const data = React.useMemo(() => props.tabledata, [props.tabledata])

const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({ columns, data }, useSortBy)
```

The last line throws the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

I've been through the issues in react-table repo and it seems like this was raised as a problem in a version update but it seems long ago solved. I've search all over for other clues, but am stumped!

I'm using: `react-table": "^7.2.0", "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i don't see `forEach` being called anywhere on this post ? am i missing something.

Comment: @BARNOWL my guess is its enacted within useSortBy

Comment: Can you check to see what you're getting for `columns` and `data`

Comment: The `forEach` is in the useTable function from the react-table package:    `> 585 |   data.forEach((originalRow, rowIndex) =>
  586 |     accessRow(originalRow, rowIndex, 0, undefined, rows)`

Comment: @BARNOWL `columns` and `data` are memoized objects. but I think this is the issue I can get it to work when I hard code the data, but when I try to add json data using useMemo it causes the errors. problem is useTable requires memoized input so I'm struggling a bit now how to convert the json return data from the api to memoized data in a way that the useTable call is happy with. the `columns` which are hard coded look identical to `data` when they are both converted back to json and console logged.

Comment: solved with a bit of a hack, created a function which I pass to use memo which transcribes the json into a hard coded version of the json elements. Hopefully I'll figure out something more reasonable and refactor later.... thanks all!

Comment: Sorry. Could you let me know what kind of function you made? I'm also stuck same as your problem...

Answer (score 3):

The same error occurs if some forgets to pass `data` property to the `useTable` hook.

In my case it was the incorrect parameter name.

```
const changes = ...;
const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
    } = useTable({ columns, changes });
```

The fix is:

```
useTable({ columns, data: changes });
```

This is not the exact solution for the asked question but might be handy for others.

Answer (score 1):

mine was shouting

```
TypeError: data.forEach is not a function accessRowsForColumn node_modules/react-table/dist/react-table.development.js:1453
```

I wanted to create a table with just one row - I was passing an object into data, but it needed to be an object within an array, so I simply did

```
<Table
columns={columns}
data={[myObject]}
/>
```

Comment: If this is the workaround that solved your problem, then mark it as accepted to help others know it